# Loading file from path contained in tf.Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I build a simple model using `tf.keras` and a `tf.data.Dataset` for efficient loading as the dataset is a couple of GBs big.

The images are in `tiff` format and therefore need to be loaded directly as `numpy.array`.

I do have a dataset of labels and file paths and want to map a function for loading on that dataset. Therefore, I somehow have to get the python string representation out of the tensor.

I tried using the usual `tf.Tensor.eval()` and then joining the chars to a full string but getting the err: `ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using` eval()`: No default session is registered.` which does make sense as there is no session before the keras model is being executed

Then I tried putting `tf.enable_eager_execution()` right below my tensorflow import in the dataset file (and changing to from `.eval()` to `.numpy()`) but am getting err: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has not attribute 'numpy'` hinting `tf.enable_eager_execution()` did not work

Basically I'm trying to read a string contained in a tensor a below:

```
path = tf.decode_raw(path, tf.uint8)
path = ''.join(map(chr, path.eval()))  # with session
path = ''.join(map(chr, path.numpy()))  # with eager execution

image = PIL.Image.open(path)
image = numpy.array(image)
```

Both work fine when 'prototyping' in a single file without the rest but do not work when having e.g. my model in a `model.py` and dataset in `dataset.py` but having `tf.enable_eager_execution()` in both

Comment: Any new solutions to this problem? I think this might be solved when we find a way to convert the string type tensor to numpy. I am still experiencing this issue...

Comment: not from my side @krenerd. I haven't used tf for a long time and also did not experience such issues.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is quite old but as it could  be useful for someone esle, that would be my approach:

You can use tf.io.read_file to read the file and then convert it to an image with [tf.image.decode_png](http://tensorflow.biotecan.com/python/Python_1.8/tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_png.html) if your image is a png. Several other formats are available.

with **tf_filepath** the path to your RGB image contained in a tensor

```
image = tf.io.read_file(tf_filepath)
image = tf.image.decode_png(image, channels=3, dtype=tf.uint8)
```

Comment: this might have been an option. thanks for sharing!  As I haven't used tf in a long time I cannot confirm.